# Clear scrollsaver.min.js information

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, scrollbar

I had a problem with dynamically created labels (with scrollbars) not keeping the scroll position when the page was refreshed. I was proposed a solution that works well, the scrollsaver.min.js script.

However, I reset some variables when the asp.net session is started and this script seems to keep those values. Is there a way to clear the cookie generated by this script on session_start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to remove the cookies, then it's really very easy and straightforward. if you know the names of those specific cookies, then you can use **Request.Cookies.Remove("cookiename")** to remove the cookie. 
Inside firefox, you can view the cookies from the "PageInfo->Security->View Cookies" option.

Comment: That's perfect. I was able to get the name of the cookie and remove it :)